# Connect different multiple attributes between two different nodes

Tags: python, maya

i am trying to auto connect multiple attributes at once.
[image]

Right now I am creating two different lists, one for the left node and one for the right.
I am listing there the attributes and then I want with a loop to connect each one attribute of left list to the coordinate attribute of right list. (Both lists have the same number of elements).
Here is what I have at the moment but it pops an error in the loop:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


left_LIST = {}
customAttrList = cmds.listAttr('null1',k=True,ud=True)
if customAttrList:
    for attr in customAttrList:
        left_LIST[attr] = cmds.getAttr('null1'+'.'+attr)
print left_LIST
    
    
right_LIST = cmds.aliasAttr('blendShape1', q=1)
print right_LIST

i=0

for i in range(len(left_LIST)):
    cmds.connectAttr('null1.' + left_LIST[i], 'blendshape1.'+ right_LIST[i])
```

Comment: Please post the error message you mentioned. But from what seems to be obvious is that your construction of attributes for the `connectAttr()` command is wrong. If I'm not mistaken, you create a dictionary with attribute names as keys and in the loop you try to iterate over the dictionary using integers keys but your keys are attribte names, so I suppose you get an key error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the number of both attributes are the same, this should work.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

customAttrList = cmds.listAttr('null1',k=True,ud=True)        
right_LIST = cmds.aliasAttr('blendShape1', q=1)

for index, value in enumerate(customAttrList):
    cmds.connectAttr('null1.' + value, 'blendshape1.'+ right_LIST[index])
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your time i will check it